# Vertex Displacement Shader Graph With The Camera Moving Issue

Tags: unity, camera, movement, unity-shader-graph, vertex-shader

I have a foliage sway shader, that works well.

[image]

[image]

But when the camera moves the vertex displacement stops:

[image]

And the weird thing also is that if I move the camera to the right nothing seems to happen, but moving the camera only to the left causes the issue.

Googling shows that the position node's world space takes camera position into account, and the presumed fix is to change all position nodes to absolute world space, and also make the transform node convert from absolute world to object space. But that didn't fix it sadly. Any ideas could help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has the same problem, you can replace the Position node that feeds the GradientNoise UVs with the UV node.
You can find more details [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1894543/vertex-displacement-shader-graph-with-the-camera-m.html).

Comment: Link-only answers are sensitive to link rot, and this could make them useless on the long term. Please include additional information from your source, so that your solution could still be working even if that forum thread were deleted.